# How do to a safety knot when abseiling with 2 ropes?

Tags: climbing, prusik, rappelling

If I'm abseiling with a double rope what's the common way to add a safety knot? Is it a prusik knot around the 2 ropes instead of 1 or something like 2 prusiks?

Comment: Apparently the knot can go around the 2 ropes like here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ejvqrb&s=6#.VCiGWBbfGZg

Comment: Most people use an autoblock, not a Prusik.